# Making the module structure trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, quotient-group, free-modules

Let $G$ be a group (not necessarily abelian) acting on an abelian group $M$. Consider the group ring $\Bbb Z[G]$ (which is in fact an algebra). The action of $G$ on $M$ makes $M$ as a $\Bbb Z[G]$-module in an obvious way, namely, 
$$ (\sum _i n_i g_i) a:=\sum_i n_i (g_i a).$$

Suppose $M$ is a free $\Bbb Z[G]$-module. Viewing $M$ as an abelian group, let $N$ be the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $ga-a$, for $g \in G$ and $a\in M$, and consider the quotient group $M/N$. Is there something that we can say about the resulting group $M/N$? It seems like it would be a free abelian group, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your quotient $M/N$ is always trivial. For all $a\in M$, you have $a=(1_R+1_R)a-a\in N$, so $M=N$.Or did I misunderstand your definition of $N$ ?

Comment: @GreginGre Oops sorry, actually what I wanted is little bit different. I will make an edit.

Comment: My answer still holds, i think.

Comment: @GreginGre Sorry again, I forgot to change the definition of N.

Comment: For $M=\Bbb{Z}[G]$ you clearly get $M/N\cong\Bbb{Z}$ as $N$ is the kernel of the map $\sum_in_ig_i\mapsto\sum_in_i$. If $M$ is a free $\Bbb{Z}[G]$-module it is a direct sum of copies of $\Bbb{Z}[G]$, so the quotient is a direct sum of copies of $\Bbb{Z}$, i.e. a free abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first consider the case that $M = \mathbb{Z}[G]$ is free of rank $1$. The map $$ \varepsilon : \mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z}, g \mapsto 1 $$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module homomorphism if we give $\mathbb{Z}$ the trivial $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module structure and its kernel is $N = \left< g a - a \:|\: g \in G, a \in M \right>$. In fact, $N \subseteq \ker(\varepsilon)$ is clear and conversely, if we have $a  = \sum_{g \in G} a_g g \in \ker(\varphi)$, then $\sum_{g \in G} a_g = 0$ and so 
$$ a = \sum_{g \in G} a_g g -  \sum_{g \in G} a_g e = \sum_{g \in G} a_g (g e - e) \in N $$
where $e \in G$ denotes the identity element. It follows that $\varepsilon$ induces an isomorphism $M/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and thus the quotient is a free abelian group of rank $1$.

In general, with $M$ being a free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, $M$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, say $M \cong \mathbb{Z}[G]^{\oplus T}$ and under such an isomorphism $N$ will correspond to a direct sum of copies of $\ker(\varepsilon)$, i.e. $N \cong \ker(\varepsilon)^{\oplus T}$ and this will yield $M/N \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus T}$, a free abelian group.